# Notification Icon Issue

Tags: android, performance, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

Notification Icon is not appearing in redmi MI device,it appears the default ic_launcher while in every other devices image is appears.API 22 and Android 5.1.1
and minsdk=15,target=24.I had tested in many other mobiles there is no issue but in my device this issue is there.Can you please get rid out from this problem. my code is

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.home1);  //icon appears in device notification bar and right hand corner of notification
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.home1));        
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);      
            builder.setContentTitle(Title);        
    builder.setContentText(message);        
    builder.setSubText(subtext);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);        
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have different versions of drawable home1 for hdpi,xhdpi etc.??

Comment: yeah i have but still not image icon not coming...

Comment: Please check whether all versions of drawable home1 are similar.

Comment: yep i checked once again and no all .png images have different sizes like hdpi has 20*20 and other have other...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use two icon in your notification. first one is small white png so that it will show in status bar and second one is app logo.

Update white icon in below folder with difference size.

1. hdpi (36x36)
2. mdpi (24x24)
3. xhdpi (48x48)

Suppose this image name is app_logo_white_small.png.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setLargeIcon(
                    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                            getResources(), R.drawable.app_icon))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_logo_white_small)
            .setContentTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setContentText(msg)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentIntent(getPendingIntent())
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

 notificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notificationBuilder.build());
```

I hope, it will help you.

Comment: still Image is not working in my device but it perfectly shoes msg and all

Comment: can you please share your icon also or notification screen shot

Comment: 150 %sure coz it appears right in genymotion and other devices too except redmi note 3

Comment: sure but how coz i have no reputation to share screenshot?

Comment: default ic_launcher is coming in my device